# TypeError: unhashable type: 'bytearray'

Tags: python, django, python-3.4, mysql-connector-python

I'm new to django and trying to create a Homepage. But I've already problems with the database setup. When I run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get this error

```
(env) paul@Kreker-Server:~/public_html/p_kreker$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: auth, sessions, contenttypes, admin
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/paul/public_html/p_kreker/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/paul/public_html/p_kreker/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/paul/public_html/p_kreker/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/paul/public_html/p_kreker/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/paul/public_html/p_kreker/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 165, in handle
    emit_post_migrate_signal(created_models, self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias)
  File "/home/paul/public_html/p_kreker/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 268, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    using=db)
  File "/home/paul/public_html/p_kreker/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 198, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/home/paul/public_html/p_kreker/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 64, in create_permissions
    if not is_latest_migration_applied('auth'):
  File "/home/paul/public_html/p_kreker/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 292, in is_latest_migration_applied
    loader = MigrationLoader(connection)
  File "/home/paul/public_html/p_kreker/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/paul/public_html/p_kreker/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 184, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/paul/public_html/p_kreker/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 60, in applied_migrations
    return set(tuple(x) for x in self.migration_qs.values_list("app", "name"))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'bytearray'
```

I'm using python-3.4, django-1.7.4 and for the SQL connection mysql-connector-python-2.0.2. For this project I've created a virtual environment with the python 3 venv. I host this project on github: https://github.com/pkreker/p_kreker

Thank you in advance!

edit settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for p_kreker project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '@l)bvja@q45ud2d813g*i+n2=1#kbf#nzqm6()c)dv116pqq^p'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'p_kreker.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'p_kreker.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'p_kreker',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'paul',
        'PASSWORD': 'm2aJup2fHYDdArGT',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-de'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: can you post your database config  ? is in setting.py file

Comment: Did you prefix something in your settings with a `b` perhaps? (`b'blabla'`). That would create a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-methods)

Comment: I've added the settings.py. I hope it helps. All the other code is on GitHub. The link is: https://github.com/pkreker/p_kreker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error today. I had created my db as `utf8_bin` collation, which I assume was the reason for it. Dropped the DB, re-created with `utf8_general_ci`, ran migrations, and it worked fine.

Comment: You are right... I did the same stupid mistake :( Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Since the bug headline does not specify "Django", I expect a number of Python 3 newbies will end up here.  Note that the hashable/immutable counterpart to "bytearray" is the type "bytes".

```
>>> b1 = bytearray([1, 2, 3])
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(b1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'bytearray'
>>> b2 = bytes(b1)
>>> b2
b'\x01\x02\x03'
>>> s.add(b2)
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is likely to be a bug in mysql-connector-python - does it support Django 1.7.4? Your code works fine if you run it with sqlite.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I talked to some django developers and they said the same thing. I've reported a bug at mysql bugreport. I'd like to fix the bug, but I'm very new to python... so I'll have to wait till they fix the bug.

Comment: I'm a Django core dev too - glad they agreed :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the project is on an older version of Django for example 1.11.16, try explicit decoding by calling the method `.decode("utf-8")`  in introspection.py file.

```
if django.VERSION >= (1, 8):
            return [
                TableInfo(row[0].decode("utf-8"), {'BASE TABLE': 't', 'VIEW': 'v'}.get(row[1].decode("utf-8")))
                for row in cursor.fetchall()
            ]
        else:
            return [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

introspection.py file path: 
`C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\django\introspection.py`

method prototype: 
`def get_table_list(self, cursor):`

Comment: I encountered the same problem in Django 2.1.5 with mysql-connector-python 8.0.5. This method of explicit decoding worked like a miracle. Thanks.